# Important numbers in Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers, stirling-numbers, catalan-numbers

I recently went through some important numbers like the Stirling and Bell number for calculation of partitions /equivalence relations.

I was wondering if someone can help me get a list of important numbers and their applications in Combinatorics ;
like Catalan , Fibonacci , Stirling etc.???

Comment: Euler's number.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number

Comment: Genocchi numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genocchi_number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some that I’ve encountered; the Wikipedia links generally give some indication of their applications.

[Bell numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number)
[ordered Bell (or Fubini) numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number)
[Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)
[Delannoy numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number)
[Euler(ian) numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number)
[Fibonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)
[Genocchi numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genocchi_number)
[Lah numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lah_number)
[Motzkin numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motzkin_number)
[partition numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29)
[Schröder numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der_number)
[Schröder-Hipparchus numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Hipparchus_number)
[Stirling numbers of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)
[Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)

And perhaps we should include a couple of non-integer sequences:

[Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_numbers)
[Harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)

**Added:** And we also have the [*nimbers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber) or *Grundy numbers*, though they are the ordinal numbers with new operations of addition and multiplication rather than a distinguished subset of the integers.

Comment: Thanks Brian for your answer .
Also I would like to add the Grundy Numbers/Nimbers- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber
 to your list.

Comment: @Amartya: You’re welcome. I didn’t include those because what distinguishes them is the operations on them rather than their specific values, but I’m happy to do so.

Answer (score 1):

There are some sequences which I feel embarrassed that I do not recognize immediately (well, I do know the Catalan numbers).
Here are these numbers sequences (or arrays of numbers sometimes) which
I feel I encounter on a daily basis.

[image: Sequences of combinatorial flavor]